# GitHub server-side clone repo

Tags: git, github, git-clone

On GitHub, I would like to create a clone of a repo.  Not a branch or fork, but clone a repo into a new totally distinct repo. Hopefully I can accomplish this purely on the server-side ( i.e. not involving local repos ) and then git-clone the just-cloned repo to a local repo.

Comment: If you have the ability for a local repo (as the last sentence implied) why not just clone to a local repo then push to the fresh new repo?

Comment: I'd venture to say that if you need to do something on server side, you'll need access to that server side, in other words something like ssh. :-) I'm not aware of Github exposing the 'git clone' command through the web interface. You're probably better off checking out, checking back into your own repo.

Comment: Ok I'm fine with clone-to-local and push, but how exactly do I push to a fresh new repo ? I was thinking of (i) create a new server-side empty repo (ii) clone it to a local-folder (iii) copy-paste the code into this folder (iv) push it up.  But is this really the same thing as cloning the repo ?  Do I retain all logs and other metadata ?

Answer (score 4):

Server-side cloning without forking is not currently supported by Github.

To duplicate a repo via a local clone, you can just follow the Github help article [Duplicating a repo](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository).

If there is a good reason why you can't clone it and push it back (e.g. repo size is astronomical AND you dont need a local clone because you're doing this for a client), you can try [contacting Github support](https://help.github.com/contact) and asking them to do it for you. (Again, they'll probably only do it if you have a pretty good reason)

Comment: just saw this answer, which is the way to go if you want to clone the entire repo and not a specific branch

Answer (score 0):

Create a new repo on your GitHub account and get the URL, let's assume it's

```
https://github.com/baltostar/myproject.git
```

Clone the repo you are interested in:

```
git clone https://github.com/otheruser/project.git
cd project
```

Add your GitHub repo as a new remote:

```
git remote add balto-github https://github.com/baltostar/myproject.git
```

Push the branch you are interested in into your new repo:

```
git push balto-github master
```

Or optionally use the `:` syntax to specify a new name for the branch if the existing one doesn't suit you:

```
git push balto-github localbranch:newbranchname
```

From there, you can scratch your local repo completely

```
cd ..
rm -rf project
```